# How to add comma in between curly braces notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a set of json messages.. I am trying to format my messages such that i can add a comma inbetween every instance i see a }{

Below is an example of my  json i mfile i have 100s but not all have commas between each message. I thought i should try and find }{ but it doesn't work...

```
[{

    "OrderID": "554",

}
NEED TO ADD COMMA HERE
{

    "OrderID": "554",

}
NEED TO ADD COMMA HERE
{

    "OrderID": "123",

}]
```

How do i do this quickly using Notepad++?

Comment: That should work. Why you say it doesn't work? Can you share your regex that you tried?

Comment: \}|\{ is what i tried but it takes me to every bracket

Comment: i just need }{ highlight then i want to insert a comma inbetween them

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern `\}(\s*)\{` and replace it with pattern`\}\n,\1\{`

Explanation:

`\}` - match `}` literally

`(\s*)` - match zero or more white sapces and store it into capturing group

`\{` - match `{` literally

Replacement: `\1` - paste what is in first capturing group